# How to skip dependency on all for package target?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I have a project with few separate build targets, which are exclusive - but they're built from the same sources, just in other configurations, targets etc.
I need the install and package targets to be independent from *all* target, which is a default. For the install target there's a *CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY* variable, which works very well and do what I need. 
How to turn the dependency from *all* for CPack's output off, too?

Comment: For now, the only way to overcome this is using _EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL_ for some of the targets, but the better solution would be to CPack understanding the _EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD_*_ flags.

Answer (score 0):

You answered the question more or less yourself: `CMAKE_SKIP_PACKAGE_ALL_DEPENDENCY` [is available](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/546c839d04d3be09b0f54f7f107d7381c17af2a8)

Comment: Ah, it's nowhere in the docs, in any of versions... Thanks, I'll try it :)